# Setting Pixel (i,j) in Color Image to Black in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm looking to segment a color image in order to try and identify certain features. I'm looking to set a pixel to black if it does not meet some decision rule, else I want to leave the pixel the exact same as it was when it was first read.

I'm reading the image using:

```
Mat apples = imread("C:/Users.......", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

My attempts so far have been, for setting a pixel in row i and column j to black:

```
apples.at<uchar>(i,j) = 0;
```

Which, when looping over all rows and columns of the image seems to skip over 2/3rds of the image.

I've also tried:

```
Vec3b black;

black[0] = 0;
black[1] = 0;
black[2] = 0; 

apples.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = black;
```

Which seems to almost filter the image as. Any help would be appreciated!

*edit* I'm looping over the image matrix as follows:

```
 for(int i=0;i<apples.rows;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<apples.cols;j++)
                        {
                            if(applescopy[0].at<uchar>(i,j) == 0 || applescopy[1].at<uchar>(i,j) == 0 || applescopy[2].at<uchar>(i,j) == 0 )
                              {
                                apples.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = black;
                              }
                        }
                }
```

If I eliminate the "if" statement at the end of the second for and just set apples.at uchar (i,j) = 0; unconditionally, only the left third of the image will become black.

*edit 2* I believe my use of "split" on the original color image seemed to modify the original color image. I've since made a copy of it for use in the loop and am getting more expected results, thanks guys!

Comment: Please post the code that you say is skipping over 2/3rds of the image so we can help you out.

Comment: .at<uchar>(i,j) does access the i,j uchar value which is i,j pixel if you have a 8 bit grayscale image, but if you have a color image you have to use 3 times as many "columns" because 3 uchar values are one RGB value. easiest is to use .at<Vec3b>(i,j) if you have 3 channel with 8 bit each.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a pixel value to white in a color image after certain condition is true.  I have changed it to white you can set it black by replacing 255 to 0.The below piece of code will do the work.

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include<highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main( ) {

Mat originalImage = imread("5.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); 

  if (originalImage.empty()){ 
    cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;         
    return -1;
  } 

 for(int i=0;i<originalImage.rows;i++)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<originalImage.cols;j++)
  {
   if(originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] == 0 || originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] == 0 || originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] == 0 )
    {
     //originalImage.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = 255;
     originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]=255; // change it to white
     originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1]=255;
     originalImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2]=255;
        //   cout << i<<" " <<j<< endl; 
     }
   }
 }
 imwrite("result.png",originalImage);
namedWindow("MyWindow",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("MyWindow", originalImage); 
waitKey(0);  
destroyWindow("MyWindow");
return 0;
 }
```

Hope this is what you need!!Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

for 3 channel 24 bit image you can acces by uchar but the each column is a single channel value, so you would have to assume 3 times the number of channels! Or you just use Vec3b to access the pixel everywhere:

```
 for(int i=0;i<apples.rows;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<apples.cols;j++)
                    {
                     // read whole pixel value, which is a Vec3b for most color images. If you only read uchars you would have to multiply column index by 3 and add the channel number (0..2)
                     cv::Vec3b & pixel = applescopy[0].at<Vec3b>(i,j)
                     // decompose the pixel to three channels
                     uchar & B = pixel[0];
                     uchar & G = pixel[1];
                     uchar & R = pixel[2];
                     // test for any condition, e.g. if one of RGB is 0
                        if( anyCondition )
                          {
     //set whole Vec3b to some value
                            apples.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = black;
                          }
                    }
            }
```